# get registry with the greatest date

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a problem, this is my table [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GftR2.png)

I want to get the items that are most date, for example:
 X_1   sp0127   0.00018
 X_2   sp0125   0.004

Comment: Welcome to SO. Here you find something on [ask] and [mcve]. You could start by posting data as formatted text and explaining what you tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle? Use a row_number()

```
select Item, Prov, Costo
from 
(
select Item, Prov, Costo, row_number() over(partition by Item order by Fecha desc) as Pick_Ord
from Table1
)
where Pick_Ord =1
```

Comment: It would be more efficient to select `max(fecha) over (partition by item) as max_fecha` and use `where fecha = max_fecha` in the outer query, instead of `row_number()`. The point being, if all we need is the max, there is no reason to spend the time to order the entire partition by fecha. Finding the max in a set is much cheaper than ordering the entire set.

Comment: @mathguy Thanks, every day is a school day

Answer (score 0):

"I want to get the items that are most date"
 as i may suggest you wanted something like table sorted by date

```
select * from some_table st
order by st.fecha;
```

or you wanted only the last date:

```
select * from some_table st
where st.fecha = max(st.fecha);
```